# Issue with creating a PostgreSQL 9.5 replica

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am trying to create a hot-standby replica for a PostgreSQL 9.5 master.

The basic process I have used is to start a backup on the master:

```
SELECT pg_start_backup('label', true)
```

On the slave, I then run, pg_basebackup:

```
pg_basebackup -h <master ip> -D /data/pgsql/9.5/data -U replicator -v -P  --xlog-method=stream
```

Once this completes, I execute the command to stop the backup on the master:

```
SELECT pg_stop_backup()
```

At this point, I got the following on STDOUT:

```
NOTICE:  pg_stop_backup cleanup done, waiting for required WAL segments to be archived
WARNING:  pg_stop_backup still waiting for all required WAL segments to be archived (60 seconds elapsed)
HINT:  Check that your archive_command is executing properly.  pg_stop_backup can be canceled safely, but the database backup will not be usable without all the WAL segments.
```

This continues and doesn't exit.

The archive command on the master is set to:

```
rsync -a %p <replica ip>:/data/wal-archive/%f
```

Initially, this wasn't working, as the server key need to be accepted. Once I did this manually, the rsync started, and I can see a large build up of files (~ 15GB so far) in /data/wal-archive.

This is a 20TB DB, so I really don't want to have to start this process again by messing something up.

Is it safe to just exit out of the terminal issuing the WARNINGS? I have read in other posts that archive_mode only needs to be on during the process of streaming the DBs to the replica for the purposes of setting up the replica, and beyond that it isn't required.

In that case, can I just do a CTRL-C on the terminal and proceed to configure the replica?

Can I then turn archive_mode off on the master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to CTRL-C out of the pg_stop_backup().

The build up of files in the /data/wal_archive directory arises from the archive_command on the master.

Once the postgres service is started on the slave, these "logs" are consumed (ie written to the DB on the slave) and then deleted.